# Multiple Videos On Screen

Tags: vegas-pro

I'm trying to get a whole bunch of videos on screen, playing at one time. The idea would be to slowly pan into the central video. Any ideas how this can be achieved? I'm using Sony Vegas Pro 9. I've attached these two pictures to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]
[image]

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Track Motion to create video wall - 9 tracks, each clip on its own track. There are tools that can help you to do it (I use Pan/Crop Assistant from [Vegasaur toolkit](http://vegasaur.com/Vegasaur)).
Add another track (parent track) and make these 9 tracks composing childs of this parent track.
Use Parent Motion to create pan/zoom animation.

Read in the Help about Track Motion...

Answer (score 1):

Im would guess theres a plugin for SV that would do this but I would do the following which might be a bit long winded and not correct but it will do the job.

Assuming your using HD 1920 x 1080

Get all 9 videos each on a different timeline (stacked one above the other)
Resize them all to the same size 

width = (1920 / 3 = 640 - 10px for the 2 borders)

height = (1080 / 3 = 360 - 10px for the 2 borders)

Then position the 3 central videos starting from the middle one and working up and down then left and right

Otherwise what has just sprung into my head

using something like photoshop make a quick template (ie the image above to mate the 
output size assuming 1920 x 1080

drop this on a timeline

shrink all the videos to fit the boxes

remove template from timeline